# NTFS Journal USN_REASON_HARD_LINK_CHANGE event

Tags: windows, ntfs, journal

I've written a program that reads the NTFS index and journal similar to what is described here:
http://ejrh.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/using-the-ntfs-journal-for-backups/
And It works fairly well.
In addition to the normal journal events `USN_REASON_CLOSE`, `USN_REASON_FILE_CREATE`, `USN_REASON_FILE_DELETE` etc' I'm receiving an event with reason **`USN_REASON_HARD_LINK_CHANGE`**. I'd like to be able to update the directory index according to this event but I can't find any information about it. The [only documentation is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> An NTFS file system hard link is added to or removed from the file or
>   directory. An NTFS file system hard link, similar to a POSIX hard
>   link, is one of several directory entries that see the same file or
>   directory.

What does this mean? where was the hard-link created? or was it removed? how do I get more information about what happened?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ancient, but I stumbled upon this while researching a related problem.  Here's what I found:  The hard-links are a complicating factor when reading the USN.  You can get journal entries describing change to a single file reference number by way of changes made through any hard-link that's been created.  Generally, and to the original question, **hard-links are alternative directory entries through which a single file might be accessed**.  Thus, all the file's characteristics are shared for each link (except for the names and parent file reference numbers).  Technically, you can't tell which entry is the original and which is a link.

A subtle difference does exist, and it manifests if you query the master file table (using DeviceIOControl and Fsctl_Enum_Usn_Data).  The query will return only a single representative file regardless of how many links exist. You can query for the links using NtQueryInformationFile, querying for FILE_HARD_LINK_INFORMATION.  I think of the entry returned by the MFT query as the main entry and the NtQueryInformationFile-returned items as links...however, the main entry can get deleted and one of the links will get promoted...so it's only a *housekeeping* thought and little else.

Note that a problem arises where one of the hard-links is moved or renamed.  In this case, the journal entries for the rename or move reflect the filename and parent file reference number of the affected link.  The problem arises if you ask for only the summary "on-close" records. In such a case, you won't ever see the USN_REASON_RENAME_OLD_NAME record...because that USN entry never gets an associated REASON_CLOSE associated with it.  Without this tidbit, you won't be able to easily determine which link's name or location was changed.  You have to read the usn with ReadOnlyOnClose set to 0 in the Read_Usn_Journal_Data_V0.  This is a far chattier query, but without it, you can't accurately associate the change with one link or the other.

Answer (score 0):

As always with the USN, I expect you'll need to go through a bit of trial and error to get it to work right.  These observations/guesses may, I hope, be helpful:

When the last hard link to a file is deleted, the file is deleted; so if the last hard link has been removed you should see USN_REASON_FILE_DELETE instead of USN_REASON_HARD_LINK_CHANGE.  I believe that each reference number refers to a file (or directory, but NTFS doesn't support multiple hard links to directories AFAIK) rather than to a hard link.  So immediately after the event is recorded, at least, the file reference number should still be valid, and point to another name for the file.

If the file still exists, you can look it up by reference number and use [`FindFirstFileNameW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends to find the current links.  Comparing this to the event record in question plus any relevant later events should give you enough information, although if multiple hard links for the same file are deleted and/or created you might not be able to reconstruct the order in which this happened, and if you don't have enough information about the prior state of the file system you might not be able to identify the deleted hard links.  I don't know whether that would matter to you or not.

If the file no longer exists, you should still be able to identify it by the USN record in which it was deleted.  Again, taking all relevant events into consideration, and with enough information about the prior state, you should be able to reconstruct most of what happened, if not the order.

There is some hope that we can do better than this: the file name and/or ParentFileReference number in the event record might refer to the hard link that was created or deleted, rather than to an arbitrary link to the file.  In this case you'll have all the relevant information about the sequence of events except for whether any particular event was a create or a delete, which you should be able to work out by looking at the current state of the file and working backwards through the records.

I assume you've already looked for nearby change records that might contain additional information?  There isn't, for example, a USN_REASON_RENAME_NEW_NAME record generated when a hard link is created or a USN_REASON_RENAME_OLD_NAME when a hard link is removed?  Or paired USN_REASON_HARD_LINK_CHANGE records, one for the file, one for the directory containing the affected hard link to the file?  (Wishful thinking, I expect, but it wouldn't hurt to look!)

For testing purposes, you can create hard links with the `mklink` command.